# Link columns in two tables and trigger to automatically update and insert data

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have done a lot of searching and have not found exactly what I am looking for. Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I did not see one that matched my needs.

I have 2 tables:

`students`:

```
ID int autoincrement
RegistrationNumber nvarchar
fullname nvarchar
address nvarchar
stream nvarchar
phone nvarchar
```

and so on

The other table is `results`:

```
ID int autoincrement
RegistrationNumber nvarchar
fullname nvarchar
stream nvarchar
GPA nvarchar
```

I want to connect these tables so that the results table get values from students table, and any insertion/update in `students` table automatically updates/inserts data accordingly in `results` table columns to be connected in both tables are `RegistrationNumber`, `fullname` and `stream`.

Comment: What searches did you try?   Learning how to search in a focused, efficient manner is going to be the most important skill you can possess as a programmer.   All the information you need to answer your question is freely and easily found on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need a trigger (or two) that will modify the table `Results` after insert or update on the `Students` table. You can start from here: [CREATE TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx).

Beside that, not sure if you can, but my suggestion is to have the table Results like this:

```
Student_ID int 
GPA nvarchar
```

In this way after each insert you have to insert only the Student_ID and when you update a student you won't need to change `Results`.

Also you can define Student_ID as a Foreign Key to be sure to keep referential integrity.